# Use Elastic Scale package within Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I would like to use the Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client package from within my Azure function.

I've added a project.json as follows:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net452":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client": "1.3.3"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Function:

```
#r "System.Data"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net; 
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    ShardMapManager shardMapManager;
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'SqlDatabase' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ShardMapManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the #r statement to [reference external assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)

The `Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client` package installs a `Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client.dll`, so then try:

`#r "Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client.dll"` or

`#r "bin\Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client.dll"`

(I've always has issues with the path).

Still, I would recommend not using the CSX scripting approach and instead use precompiled binaries using the technique described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/). Then you get the full benefit of C# and you won't have to deal with adding `#r` statement to include the assembly.

Comment: That's a greta help.  The "reference external assembly" link had the answer: I needed to change net452 to net46 within my project.json.  After that it worked fine.  I didn't need to explictly reference the assembly.  Thanks for the precompiled binaries link, that looks  a much better long-term plan.

Comment: Swicthed over to precompiled binaries and it works great.  Thanks again